# Is it possible to use AMS Euler math outside latex (Inkscape)?

Tags: fonts, inkscape, euler

I am writing a LaTeX document with AMS Euler math as math font. I need to produce some figures with Inkscape, I for consistency I want to use the same font for numbers in my figures. However, I cannot find AMS Euler math in the list of fonts installed in my system (Ubuntu 18.03). Is there any possibility to install AMS Euler math as a system font as well?

Thank you!

Comment: Not directly, but it gives me a better option actually, which is to use Textext plugin that I did not know, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

There is an OpenType conversion of AMS Euler that’s free to download, [Neo Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf).

The Latin alphabet of Khaled Hosny’s [Aref Ruqaa](https://github.com/alif-type/aref-ruqaa) is also based on Euler, but spaced for text rather than math.

Comment: Thank you, I will use Textex plugin as suggested by DG' in the comments of my question.